# Design of abstract generic DbContext class in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble implementing an abstract generic base class, using EF Core. It's probably something obvious, but I'm not seeing it.

base class:

```
public abstract class AContext<TUser> : IdentityDbContext<TUser> 
  where TUser : IdentityUser {

    public AContext(DbContextOptions<AContext<TUser>> options, ILogger<AContext<TUser>> logger) 
      : base(options) {
    }

}
```

subclass:

```
public class Context : AContext<User> {

    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options, ILogger<Context> logger)
      : base(options, logger) {   // problem is here with "options"
    }

}
```

Error: `Cannot convert from 'DbContextOptions<Context>' to 'DbContextOptions<AContext<User>>'`.

I tried casting but that doesn't work. Is the problem due to it not being covariant? Can I redesign it somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DbContextOptions<Context>` is not assignable to `DbContextOptions<AContext<TUser>>`. The reason is that there could be internal write operations to objects of type `T`, which for `DbContextOptions<Context>` would be `Context`. `DbContextOptions<AContext<TUser>>` can not provide that, because it's `T` is an `AContext<TUser>`.

Covariance is not an answer for you, since co- and contravariance is only available for interfaces, not for classes.

If you change the parameter type in your constructor from `DbContextOptions<Context>` to `DbContextOptions<AContext<User>>`, everything should work fine.

Comment: This doesn't work - although it compiles, the ASP.NET Core DI container isn't able to create instances of the context. I guess because it's abstract.

Comment: Yes, that could be the case. But that is independent of the solution. Make your class non-abstract.

Comment: @grokky: This problem is a different one than your question. If both classes are abstract, it won't work in both cases. This is a different question.